# Marking/underlining certain expressions in output pdf

Tags: output

I'm currently writing my Master's thesis and want to avoid the use of ["weasel words"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word), i.e., ambigous and vague expressions that should not be in a scientific document. Is there a simple way I can make LaTeX "find" these expressions by providing a list of them and mark them e.g. in red or underline in the final output, so I catch them when proofreading?

Comment: I am sure there is a luatex solution, but I would suggest just doing this in place, e.g., with perl: `perl -p0e 's/(?<!\\textcolor\{weaselred\}\{)(clearly|many)/\\textcolor{weaselred}{\1}/gi' yourfile > draftfile`. Here I used it for the words `clearly` and `many`. You need to define the color `weaselred` for this to work. Using this, you can 'undo' the made changes with `perl -p0e 's/\\textcolor\{weaselred\}\{(clearly|many)\}/\1/gi' draftfile > undonefile`. Of course this is a basic solution, you can expand it to your liking/needs. You could use it in a `make` file for draft versions.

Comment: There are multiple solutions here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/248632/76279