# Error automatically apply special formatting to selected words in text (XeLaTeX)

Tags: errors, xetex, xesearch

I need to color a specific word in my document  compiled with XeLaTeX engine,  following this answer [automatically apply special formatting to selected words in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107019/54817).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,xesearch}

\SearchList*{redwords}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}{hello}

\begin{document}
This is hello and this is hellow.
\end{document}
```

I have Error

> ! Undefined control sequence.  \xdef \xs@String
>   {\xs@String h}\xs@LearnLetter l.7 Thi s is hello and this is hellow.
>   The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message
>   was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., '\hobx'), type 'I'
>   and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
>   and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem as in your other question. xesearch hasn't be adapted to the new number of classes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xesearch}
\makeatletter
\chardef\xs@NatDel=4095
\XeTeXinterchartoks\xs@lrDel\xs@Classless={\xs@LearnLetter}
\XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \xs@Classless={\xs@LearnLetter}
\XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \xs@lrDel{\xs@EndString}
\makeatletter
\SearchList*{redwords}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}{hello}

\begin{document}
This is hello and this is hellow.
\end{document}
```

[image]