# Change color of all occurences of particular character in entire document

Tags: color

Is it possible to change color of all the occurrences of a particular character in entire document ?

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248632/highlight-every-occurrence-of-a-list-of-words) link provide solution for changing color of a "word" but I am looking for changing color of "a character".

Note : A character can be can be inside a word or separate.

Comment: For words, see this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248632/highlight-every-occurrence-of-a-list-of-words

Comment: awesome, couldn't find that on google search and after scrolling over links, my bad, BTW, thanks!

Comment: these solutions work for coloring "word" but if I say I want to change color of every occurrence of a character like each and every occurrence of character `a` than it doesn't works for that, any pointers on that ?

Comment: Why don't you edit the question to hone in on highlighting letters instead of words.  Then perhaps we can get it re-open.

Comment: thanks a lot! that worked. btw which language is this(on which you wrote code) ?

Comment: The language of my answer, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248632/highlight-every-occurrence-of-a-list-of-words/373361#373361, is LaTeX, using the syntax of the `listofitems` package, which was written for use in both plain TeX as well as LaTeX.  See https://ctan.org/pkg/listofitems for documentation.

Comment: Are you tied to any particular engine? Because you could for sure do this with XeTeX's interchartoken feature.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes it prints extra space after coloring the charater, why so ? @AGoldMan I don't know much about `tex` as of yet, but I am using sharelatex, and I think its pretty good(does the job).

Comment: @Vimal Make sure you added a line-ending `%` to the edited line, to prevent an extra space from being inserted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, I extend my answer at [Highlight every occurrence of a list of words?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248632/highlight-every-occurrence-of-a-list-of-words/373361#373361) to address both the highlighting of whole words as well as individual letters.

First, we have a macro `\onlywords` (default `T`) that tells the macro `\colorize{}` to operate only on whole words (meaning that `foo` would not be colorized as part of the word `xfoox`).  If `\onlywords` is set otherwise to `F`, then a search for `foo` would be colorized as part of `xfoox`.

Search letters/strings or words are set with `\setcolor{<string>}{<color>}`.

The search strings can be reset with an invocation of `\resetcolorize`.

I should note that capitalization proves to be no impediment to the string search so that `Baz` flags as a positive match for `baz`.  Further, for whole word searches, punctuation is screened out so that while `xfoox` will not be flagged when searching for the whole word `foo`. `(foo)` and `meta-foo` on the other hand will be properly located as a `foo` word.

In the MWE below, in the first paragraph, I search only for the whole words

```
\setcolor{foo}{red}
\setcolor{bar}{blue!70}
\setcolor{baz}{cyan}
\setcolor{biz}{green!70!black}
```

while in the second paragraph, I search for intraword letters

```
\setcolor{a}{red}
\setcolor{e}{orange!90!black}
\setcolor{i}{cyan}
\setcolor{o}{green!85!black}
\setcolor{u}{blue!20!blue}
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,xcolor}
\def\onlywords{T}
\def\onlywordstrue{T}
\newcounter{colorwords}
\newcommand\colorize[1]{%
  \expandafter\setsepchar\expandafter{\theparselist/ /,||.||!||?||;||:||-||(||)||[||]}%
  \reademptyitems%
  \greadlist\thewords{#1}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\thewords[]{%
    \x%
    \ifnum\xcnt<\listlen\thewords[]\relax%
      \if\relax\thewords[\xcnt,-1,-1]\relax%
        \if\relax\thewords[\the\numexpr\xcnt+1,1,1]\relax%
          \textcolor{\csname\thewordssep[\xcnt]color\endcsname}{\thewordssep[\xcnt]}%
        \else%
          \conditionalcolor{\xcnt}%
        \fi%
      \else%
        \conditionalcolor{\xcnt}%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  }%
}
\newcommand\conditionalcolor[1]{%
  \ifx\onlywords\onlywordstrue%
    \thewordssep[#1]%
  \else%
    \textcolor{\csname\thewordssep[#1]color\endcsname}{\thewordssep[#1]}%
  \fi%
}
\def\theparselist{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\setcolor[2]{%
  \stepcounter{colorwords}%
  \ifnum\value{colorwords}=1\g@addto@macro\theparselist{#1}\else%
    \g@addto@macro\theparselist{||#1}\fi
  \expandafter\def\csname#1color\endcsname{#2}%
  \edef\thestring{\Capitalize#1\relax}%
  \g@addto@macro\theparselist{||}
  \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\theparselist\expandafter{\thestring}
  \expandafter\def\csname\thestring color\endcsname{#2}%
}
\makeatother
\def\Capitalize#1#2\relax{%
  \ifcase\numexpr`#1-`a\relax
   A\or B\or C\or D\or E\or F\or G\or H\or I\or J\or K\or L\or M\or
   N\or O\or P\or Q\or R\or S\or T\or U\or V\or W\or X\or Y\or Z\else
   #1\fi#2%
}
\newcommand\resetcolorize{\gdef\theparselist{}\setcounter{colorwords}{0}}
\begin{document}
\setcolor{foo}{red}
\setcolor{bar}{blue!70}
\setcolor{baz}{cyan}
\setcolor{biz}{green!70!black}
\colorize{Lorem ipsum dolor foo sit amet bar: consectetuer adipiscing elit baz! Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Baz curabitur baz dictum gravida
mauris. Nam  biz arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, bar magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. foox xfoo ,foo foo, foo. xfoox meta -foo meta-foo
(foo)-bar.}

\def\onlywords{F}
\resetcolorize
\setcolor{a}{red}
\setcolor{e}{orange!90!black}
\setcolor{i}{cyan}
\setcolor{o}{green!85!black}
\setcolor{u}{blue!70}

\colorize{Lorem ipsum dolor foo sit amet bar: consectetuer adipiscing elit baz! Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Baz curabitur baz dictum gravida
mauris. Nam  biz arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, bar magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. foox xfoo ,foo foo, foo. xfoox meta -foo meta-foo
(foo)-bar.}
\end{document}
```

[image]