# Latex Bold a specific word without type every times \textbf{...}

Tags: bold

I wish to know is possible to set in bold a specific word without type every times `\textbf{bold}`. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textbf{dog}, cat,\textbf{dog}, cat, 
\textbf{dog}, cat, \textbf{dog}, cat 
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to set \textbf{dog} and just write "dog" which will be in bold after the compilation?

Comment: the normal way would be `\newcommand\bdog{\textbf{dog}}` ...  `\bdog`...

Comment: A simple way would also be to search and replace the string in question before compiling.

Comment: dear Greg. The solution of \usepackage{xesearch} is valid for the old version of Latex. If you try to import xesearch you will get a error message (see manual for dettails). Cheers

Comment: I added another answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107014/automatically-apply-special-formatting-to-selected-words-in-text that defines an environment that allows you to put certain words automatically in bold