# How to automatically search and assign a macro around items from a list in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, keywords, search

Suppose I have a document like this, in ConTeXt:

```
\define[1]\mymacro{{\it #1}}
\starttext
    This is some text. There are some key words in this text,
    but I need the code to automatically find
    and treat it as if `\mymacro{}` was
    written around it.
\stoptext
```

Given a list of words, is there a way to have ConTeXt mark those words, such that `\mymacro{}` is treated as being around them?

E.g. if the list of words was: key, written, as if, then the output would make "key", "written", "as if" in italics.

This will be used for more complex functions, such as automatically placing in pictures with a filename matching those the key words, e.g.:

```
\define[1]\mymacro{
    #1 \externalfigure[#1][width=\paperwidth]
}
```

Is there any way to have ConTeXt automatically treat key words as having a macro on them, even if the macro isn't manually written in?

Comment: You could try to utilize Lua for this. What do the keywords look like?

Comment: Some keywords are just one word, such as "stagecoach" but some have spaces and are capitalized, like "Christopher Columbus", "Juan de Oñate", or "George A. Custer".

Comment: https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Spellchecker

Comment: Hm, looks like the spellchecker can only color words.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [automatically apply special formatting to selected words in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107014/automatically-apply-special-formatting-to-selected-words-in-text). The answers to this post give context, lualatex and latex solutions.